# Path related problem in an attempt to save an array created by jQuery with a Rails 3 controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I used "p current_user" in the controller to see if the jquery "get" is even getting to the appropriate action in the controller. It is not! Here's the code.

Relevant portion of jquery code used to send the array (note the path):

```
      update: function(event, ui)
         {
         var sOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
         $.get('<%= update_strength_order_s_order_index_path %>', {'sOrder[]':sOrder});
         //  i confirmed this route using rake routes
         }
```

The output to the console:

```
Started GET "/s_order/update_strength_order?sOrder%5B%5D=21&sOrder%5B%5D=7&sOrder%5B%5D=13&sOrder%5B%5D=12&sOrder%5B%5D=16&sOrder%5B%5D=9&sOrder%5B%5D=11&sOrder%5B%5D=18&sOrder%5B%5D=24&sOrder%5B%5D=8" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jun 05 01:47:29 -0400 2011
```

Route:

```
  resources :s_order do
    collection do
      post :update_strength_order
    end
  end
```

Relevant rake routes result:

```
update_strength_order_s_order_index
```

Error msg in the console:

```
The action 'show' could not be found for SOrderController
```

I've just transitioned to using jQuery and am having trouble with the path thing. Since it was a jQuery get, but really a rails post, i tried both in the route and that didn't change the end result. I've Googed everything i can think of with no solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaManohar, do you think you could take a crack at this? Thanks.

Comment: replace `p request.query_string` with `debugger`. Reload, go to your console and then type `p request.query_string`. Make sure you have the debugger installed in your Gemfile

Comment: @Dex, hey Dex. Thanks for that... didn't know you could do that. Anyway, it returned "" (empty set of quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the param values. (I also am using each_with_index and just one find method).  I am assuming that you have a fixed number of sOrders for each user.

```
def update_strength_order

    sOrders = current_user.s_orders # In model: has_many :s_orders, :order => :position

    [*params['sOrder']].each_with_index do |value, index|
        str_order = index + 4 # starts with the fifth
        sOrder[str_order].update_attributes(:strength_id => value) unless sOrder[str_order].nil?
    end

    render :nothing => true
end
```

#### Suggestion

I would put this logic in the model.  It is better practice to have skinny controller and fat models.

Your controller would look something like...

```
def update_strength_order
    current_user.reposition_strength_orders_to params['sOrder']           
    render :nothing => true
end
```

while the user model...

```
def User
    has_many :s_orders, :order => :position

    def reposition_strength_orders_to(sorder_ids=[])
       [*sorder_ids].each_with_index do |value, index|
           str_order = index + 4 # starts with the fifth  
           if s_orders[str_order].nil?
               #create a new s_order
           else
               s_orders[str_order].update_attributes(:strength_id => value) 
           end
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @natedavisolds. i understand the thing about skinny controllers and fat models. i normally work everything out in the controller and then transfer as much as i can to the model.

Comment: @natedavisolds, using your controller code, the output to the console is still the same. And the result is still not being saved to the database.

Comment: Hey, @natedavisolds. I have a couple of questions about the controller code. Regarding [*params['sOrder']], what is the significance of the outside set of brackets? Secondly, what is the significance of the asterisk in the expression? I understand the rest, but regarding those two elements i don't have a clue. Thanks.

Comment: It is a handy shortcut that all works together to make sure that it is an array.  If it already is an array, it returns that array.  If it is not, then it makes an array with the first item being that value. If it is nil, returns an empty array. [* nil] => [], [* "string"] => ["string"], [* [1,2,3] ] => [1,2,3]

Comment: Do you already have sOrders for the current_user?  If you don't, none of the code that we've put in will create them.

Comment: Hi, @natedavisolds. Yes... the records are created earlier in the client's interaction with us. Good info above... put it into my notes. Thanks.

Comment: @natedavisolds, phew am i glad to put this sucker behind me. Your solution was the most significant part of the solution. The thing that was throwing me off was missing sOrders vs sOrder in your solution. When i took the extra "s" off... it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse it out by hand

Something like:

```
vars = request.query_string.split("&")
sOrder = vars.map{|var| var.split("=")[1]}
```

**EDIT**

Okay forget what I said *groan*.

Just modify your JS to look like:

```
$.get('/test', {'x[]': [567,233,678]});
// in your case
$.get('<%= update_strength_order_s_order_index_path %>', {'sOrder[]':sOrder});
```

Not sure what's up with that path either `update_strength_order_s_order_index_path` so make sure that's correct too.

Comment: thanks. When i try "p request.query_string" in the controller it comes up "". So it is not accessible to the controller. You have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste your controller method.

Comment: Hey @Dex, had to give you a point on the comment above because you have invested so much in this. Thanks!